# How to find the region in angles that match the following conditions?

Tags: symbolic, regions

Consider the following function:

```
costhd[Em_, thm_, phm_, mm_, Edrest_, md_, th_,  
  ph_] = (mm (Em Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] mm Cos[th] + 
      Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] mm^2 Cos[th] + 
      Edrest Em Sqrt[Em^2 - mm^2] Cos[thm] + 
      Edrest mm Sqrt[Em^2 - mm^2] Cos[thm] + 
      Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[th] Cos[thm]^2 + 
      Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[thm] Cos[ph] Cos[
        phm] Sin[th] Sin[thm] + 
      Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[thm] Sin[th] Sin[
        thm] Sin[ph] Sin[phm]))/((Em mm + 
      mm^2) \[Sqrt](Edrest^2 Em^2 - 
       md^2 mm^2 + (Edrest^2 - md^2) (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[th]^2 Cos[
         thm]^2 + (Edrest^2 - md^2) (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[ph]^2 Cos[
         phm]^2 Sin[th]^2 Sin[thm]^2 + 
       2 Edrest Em Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] Sqrt[Em^2 - mm^2]
         Sin[th] Sin[thm] Sin[ph] Sin[phm] + 
       Edrest^2 Em^2 Sin[th]^2 Sin[thm]^2 Sin[ph]^2 Sin[phm]^2 - 
       Em^2 md^2 Sin[th]^2 Sin[thm]^2 Sin[ph]^2 Sin[phm]^2 - 
       Edrest^2 mm^2 Sin[th]^2 Sin[thm]^2 Sin[ph]^2 Sin[phm]^2 + 
       md^2 mm^2 Sin[th]^2 Sin[thm]^2 Sin[ph]^2 Sin[phm]^2 + 
       2 Cos[ph] Cos[phm] Sin[th] Sin[
         thm] (Edrest Em Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] Sqrt[
           Em^2 - mm^2] + (Edrest^2 - md^2) (Em^2 - mm^2) Sin[th] Sin[
            thm] Sin[ph] Sin[phm]) + 
       2 Cos[th] Cos[
         thm] (Edrest Em Sqrt[Edrest^2 - md^2] Sqrt[
           Em^2 - mm^2] + (Edrest^2 - md^2) (Em^2 - mm^2) Cos[ph] Cos[
            phm] Sin[th] Sin[
            thm] + (Edrest^2 - md^2) (Em^2 - mm^2) Sin[th] Sin[
            thm] Sin[ph] Sin[phm])))
```

It represents the cosine of some angle in terms of some parameters `Em, thm, phm, mm, Edrest, mdrest,th,ph`.

I need to find the domain of values of `th,ph` for which, for the given other parameters, `costhd` would be within some values `costh1`, `costh2`. Or, preferably, the analytic relation for `th,ph` such that `costhd` corresponds to some particular value `costh`.

Example parameters are

```
mmtest = 3;
Emtest = 45;
mdtest=0.4;
Edresttest=(mmtest^2+mdtest^2-0.7^2)/(2*mmtest);
thmtest = 0.3;
phmtest = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
{costh1,costh2}={Cos[0.22],Cos[0.24]};
```

Could you please tell me whether it may be possible with Mathematica?

**Some visualization**

This is how the 3D plot of how the unit vector `{Cos[ph]Sin[th],Sin[ph]Sin[th],Cos[ph]}` looks like if requiring `costh` to be within `Cos[0.22]` and `Cos[0.221]`:

[image]

I obtained it by considering 10^6 random combinations of `th`, `ph`, and using `phm = 0.8`. It is very time-consuming process.